# Stopping previous item in RecyclerView MediaPlayer

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, error-handling, android-mediaplayer

I have a `RecyclerView` in which each item contains a button that plays sound from online url.

The problem is that I don't want the items to play sound at the same time and when you click on different sound, the previous one gets off but I don't know how can I do that ?

I would be appreciate if you could guide me through this problem

```
public class VersionAdapter3 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VersionAdapter3.VersionViewholder> {

Context context;
List<Version3> versionsList;
final Mediaplayer mediaplayer=new Mediaplayer();




public VersionAdapter3(Context context, List<Version3> versionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.versionsList = versionsList;

}

  @NonNull
@Override
public VersionViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw3,parent,false);
    return new VersionViewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VersionViewholder holder, int position) {
    Version3 version3 = versionsList.get(position);
    holder.codeNameTxt.setText(version3.getCodeName());
    holder.versionTxt.setText(version3.getVersion());
    holder.descriptiontxt.setText(version3.getDescription());


    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(version3.getSong());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();




    boolean isExpandable = versionsList.get(position).isExpandable();
    holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

   holder.btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    version3.setIsplaying(false);

                }

            }
            try {

                            if (holder.btnplay.getText().toString().equals("pause")) {
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                                version3.setIsplaying(false);
                                holder.btnplay.setText("play");

                            }

                        else {

                             holder.btnplay.getText().toString().equals("play");
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                holder.btnplay.setText("pause");
                                version3.setIsplaying(true);
                            }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        holder.btnplay.setText("play");
                    }
                });

            }

    });



}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return versionsList.size();
}

public class VersionViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView codeNameTxt, versionTxt, descriptiontxt;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    RelativeLayout expandableLayout;
    Button btnplay;
    public VersionViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {


        super(itemView);
   codeNameTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.codename);
        versionTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.version);
        descriptiontxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        btnplay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_play);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandable);


        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                Version3 version3 = versionsList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                version3.setExpandable(!version3.isExpandable());
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

when i click on the each item it get expanded and previous sound gets off but the button still shows in pause mode not play mode and I don't want the sound gets off when I expand a new item and I want that it gets off when I click on the next button
just in a case that you pause previous button it works but I want automatically it gets off when I click new play button and the previous one gets completely off
I would be so grateful if you could help me to fix my code and show me how can I edit it

Comment: If you need more help about my problem I can show you the source code too

Comment: If you have any great tutorial about it please share the link here

Comment: please add code in your question for more clearity.

Comment: I added my  adapter code for more clarity and I hope you code show me how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

The MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private VersionAdapter3 adapter;

    private List<Version3> generateVersionList() {
        List<Version3> versionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        versionsList.add(new Version3("codeName 01", "version 01", "Description 01", "https://storage.googleapis.com/2waytech-apagar/Just%20a%20Miracle%20Apart%20-%20Lost%20European.mp3", Version3.State.STOPPED));
        versionsList.add(new Version3("codeName 02", "version 02", "Description 02", "https://storage.googleapis.com/2waytech-apagar/Newspaper%20And%20Lace%20-%20Lost%20European.mp3", Version3.State.STOPPED));
        versionsList.add(new Version3("codeName 03", "version 03", "Description 03", "https://storage.googleapis.com/2waytech-apagar/The%20Man%20in%20the%20House%20of%20Cards%20-%20Lost%20European.mp3", Version3.State.STOPPED));
        return versionsList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        adapter = new VersionAdapter3(generateVersionList());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The VersionAdapter3 class:

```
public class VersionAdapter3 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VersionAdapter3.VersionViewHolder> {
    private final List<Version3> versionsList;
    private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Integer currentlyPlayingIndex = -1;

    public VersionAdapter3(List<Version3> versionsList) {
        this.versionsList = versionsList;
        this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer -> {});
    }

    private void setupMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer::start);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                        .build()
        );
    }

    private void onPlayBtnTapped(int newIndex) {

        if(newIndex != currentlyPlayingIndex && currentlyPlayingIndex != -1) {
            versionsList.get(currentlyPlayingIndex).setState(Version3.State.STOPPED);
            notifyItemChanged(currentlyPlayingIndex);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }

        if(newIndex == currentlyPlayingIndex) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                versionsList.get(newIndex).setState(Version3.State.PAUSED);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            else {
                versionsList.get(newIndex).setState(Version3.State.PLAYING);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

        } else {

            try {
                currentlyPlayingIndex = newIndex;
                Version3 version = versionsList.get(newIndex);
                String dataSource = version.getSong();
                version.setState(Version3.State.PLAYING);
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataSource);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        notifyItemChanged(newIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull VersionViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        setupMediaPlayer();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VersionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw3, parent, false);
        return new VersionViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VersionViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Version3 version3 = versionsList.get(position);

        holder.codeNameTxt.setText(version3.getCodeName());
        holder.versionTxt.setText(version3.getVersion());
        holder.descriptiontxt.setText(version3.getDescription());
        holder.adjustBtnTextByState(version3.getState());
        holder.btnplay.setOnClickListener(view -> onPlayBtnTapped(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return versionsList.size();
    }

    public static class VersionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView codeNameTxt, versionTxt, descriptiontxt;
        Button btnplay;

        public VersionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            codeNameTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.codename);
            versionTxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.version);
            descriptiontxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            btnplay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_play);
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void adjustBtnTextByState(Version3.State state) {
            switch (state) {
                case STOPPED:
                    btnplay.setText("stopped");
                    break;
                case PLAYING:
                    btnplay.setText("playing");
                    break;
                case PAUSED:
                    btnplay.setText("paused");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Version3 class

```
public class Version3 {

    private String codeName;
    private String version;
    private String description;
    private String song;
    private State state;

    public Version3(String codeName, String version, String description, String song, State state) {
        this.codeName = codeName;
        this.version = version;
        this.description = description;
        this.song = song;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCodeName() {
        return codeName;
    }

    public void setCodeName(String codeName) {
        this.codeName = codeName;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public enum State {
        STOPPED, PLAYING, PAUSED
    }
}
```

The main_activity.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the raw3.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/codename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="codename"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="version"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/codename"
        app:layout_constraintWidth="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="description"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/version"
        app:layout_constraintWidth="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/track_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="stop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/description" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I added my source code and can you help me through my code to solve my problem ?

Comment: Sure. I'm gonna edit my answer.

Comment: I tried to use your code sample and test if its work for me or no but the problem that i am facing was the part that you use Version3.State  and i am asking you that how did you use State in version 3 model cause stopped and paused and playing never came for me and it shows error and I am sending the link of error on an image for you   https://upir.ir/images/pl7izd6z4z9ddxyz8edr.jpg  and by the way thanks you for your answer and attention to my coding problem

Comment: I forgot to include the Version3 class. Sorry about that. I'm gonna edit my answer again :)

Comment: This sample code is not perfect. It can be improved. But, I believe it fits well for learning purposes.

Comment: Thanks you so much I tried it again and it worked for me and I know your sample code can  be even more complete but this was enough  for me to solve my error and bug because it was about days that I searched but couldn't fix it again thanks you for the time and paying attention